# How to use a for loop to remove lines that repeat the first number in bash?

Tags: bash, file, loops, awk, edit

By running `find /mnt/ExtraHDD1/ -type f -links +1 -printf '%i %n %p\n' | sort -n > test.txt`, I get the following output:

```
32113282 3 /mnt/ExtraHDD1/1/6.png
32113282 3 /mnt/ExtraHDD1/2/6.png
32113282 3 /mnt/ExtraHDD1/3/6.png
32113284 2 /mnt/ExtraHDD1/1/8.png
32113284 2 /mnt/ExtraHDD1/2/8.png
```

The command I ran lists all the hard-links in /mnt/ExtraHDD1/. I'm trying to generate an exclude list so that I don't upload the same file multiple times to the cloud. In each line, the first number (e.g. 32113282) represents the inode number. The second number (e.g. 3) represents the number of times the file is hard-linked. Since this is an exclude list, I want to remove the first instance of each inode number so that I exclude all copies of a hard-link except the first copy. So in this case, I want the following output:

```
32113282 3 /mnt/ExtraHDD1/2/6.png
32113282 3 /mnt/ExtraHDD1/3/6.png
32113284 2 /mnt/ExtraHDD1/2/8.png
```

How can I do this using a for loop in bash? I know how to do it in Java but bash syntax is confusing me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

If I understand correctly, first field is the key.

```
$ awk 'a[$1]++' file
32113282 3 /mnt/ExtraHDD1/2/6.png
32113282 3 /mnt/ExtraHDD1/3/6.png
32113284 2 /mnt/ExtraHDD1/2/8.png
```

Comment: Wow, the power of GNU core utils is amazing. The solution that I was thinking involved nested for-loops and was much more complicated! I really need to just bite the bullet and learn them properly. Thanks!

Comment: @karakfa : Is associative arrays initialized to zero value?

Comment: @sjsam, initialized with null, `++` forces it to be converted to numerical value.  Perhaps this will help `awk 'BEGIN{print a[1],++a[1]}'`